# CARTO Builder: show categorical data by no. of casualties

Tags: carto, cartography, cartocss

I have a categorical Carto map that shows the different types of industrial accidents, but I also want to differentiate the points based on the number of deaths i.e. the higher number of deaths, the bigger the marker width.

This is the CSS style, but I am not sure why I keep encountering an error when I apply the style.

```
 #layer {
   marker-width: 6.5;
   marker-fill: ramp([type_of_accidents], (#311271, #1D6996, #129C63, #73AF48, #EDAD08, #E17C05, #C94034), category(7));
   marker-fill-opacity: 0.5;
   marker-allow-overlap: true;
   marker-line-width: 1;
   marker-line-color: #FFF;
   marker-line-opacity: 1;
 }
 #no_of_deaths [ value <= 5] {
 marker-width: 5.0;
 }
 #no_of_deaths [ value <= 20] {
 marker-width: 15;
 }
 #no_of_deaths [ value <= 40] {
 marker-width: 25;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Styling by value using two variables can be done directly from BUILDER UI**, [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value) you have a GUIDE explaining how to do it. But if you want to use CartoCSS, the right code would be something like this:

```
#layer {
   marker-width: ramp([number_of_deaths], (5,20,40), jenks(), <=);
   marker-fill: ramp([type_of_accidents], (#311271, #1D6996, #129C63, #73AF48, #EDAD08, #E17C05, #C94034), category(7));
   marker-fill-opacity: 0.5;
   marker-allow-overlap: true;
   marker-line-width: 1;
   marker-line-color: #FFF;
   marker-line-opacity: 1;
 }
```

[Here](https://carto.com/blog/styling-with-turbo-carto/) you have a blog post that explains how to style using Turbo carto. Cheers!